# regular expression on double(10,2)

Tags: regex

I have this regularexpression

```
[0-9]+(,[0-9][0-9]?)?
```

it matches on 345563,24 but how can I limit the left side part on 8 characters?

88888888,00 - true because 8 characters 
999999999,00 - false because 9 characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
[0-9]{0,8}(,[0-9][0-9]?)?
```

`{m,n}` indicates the minimum and maximum number of occurrences of the previous character/group. You can indicate just a minimum or just a maximum by leaving one side of the expression blank. So the expression above would allow 0 to 8 occurrences of a digit. If you want 1 to 8 occurrences of a digit at the beginning of your expression, use this:

```
[0-9]{1,8}(,[0-9][0-9]?)?
```

Comment: [0-9]{,8}(,[0-9][0-9]?)? does not work, but [0-9]{0,8}(,[0-9][0-9]?)? do. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I just updated the answer. We must be using different regex manifestations.

Answer (score 2):

I would do :

```
 ^[1-9][0-9]{,7}(,[0-9][0-9]?)?$
```

- number (10,2) would be matched
- empty string won't be matched
- first digit should not be 0 (zero)

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing elements from the answers of both [@Kent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14626942/486504) and [@user1775603](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14626838/486504), I'd try the following:

```
^([1-9][0-9]{0,7}|0)(,[0-9][0-9])?$
```

This will match:

- any up-to-eight-digits number starting with a nonzero, with zero or two decimal digits after the comma
- any number >= 0 and < 1 with zero or two decimals after the comma (matching `0,xx` where `x` are digits)

Do note that the decimal separator, unless you take care to do otherwise, is very often locale-dependent. Exactly how to counteract this depends on what language and/or framework you are working with, but it's something to watch out for.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `\b` instead of `^` and `$` as in:

```
\b([1-9][0-9]{0,7}|0)(,[0-9][0-9]?)?\b
```

So that the input does not need to be fed alone and can be found in the middle of a large text too.